# Android - softkeypad adjustresize overlaps textviews

Tags: android, android-keypad

I have RelativeLayout, inside that have Edittext and below two textviews, I added adjustresize attribute in manifest, Whenever keypad opens Edit text is moving up but below two textviews are overllapping.

how to avoid this overlapping.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/retailer_ic_login_blob"
    android:id="@+id/login_blob"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="YOUR OTP NUMBER"
    android:id="@+id/lapu_text"
    android:textColor="#f8f8f8"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/otp_number"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/otp_number"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/otp_number"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

<EditText
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:maxLength="6"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/otp_number"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:background="@mipmap/retailer_ic_btn_login"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:text="RE-GENERATE"
    android:id="@+id/generate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/otp_number"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/otp_number"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/otp_number" />

 <Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:background="@mipmap/retailer_ic_btn_login"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/generate"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="SUBMIT"
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/generate"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/otp_number"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/otp_number" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#f8f8f8"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/lapu_number"
    android:layout_above="@+id/lapu_text"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lapu_text"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/lapu_text" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/retailer_ic_right"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/lapu_number"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lapu_number"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lapu_number" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login_blob"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="&#169; Copyrights 2015, All rights reserved."
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding Layout_below attribute in CopyRight TextView

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`.

Comment: I need Edittext moving up effect in my view, so this will not work

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your activity tag of your manifest file.

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: I already added this, so  that Edittext is moving up, but below Textviews under Edittext are overlapping

Answer (score 0):

adjustResize suggested by @DroidAks should work. I used your xml it looks like this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting minimum height of the layout worked for me. (android:minHeight)